# How to change push notification icon on ios?

Tags: react-native, push-notification

How to change push notification icon on ios?

I use React-native , notifee/react-native.

Like the slack push notification,
I want to use the sender's user image as the push notifications icon.

can android changes easy.

how can I change ios icon?